# Compress Java HashMap to be sent over RMI

Tags: java, compression, hashmap, rmi

We have a Client/Server application which communicates over RMI. The server sends HashMaps to the client. All works well, however when sending large HashMaps, transfer times can be slow.

Is there any way to compress the HashMaps before sending, then decompress on the client? I do not want to create any files on disk whatsoever (All must be in RAM)

Thanks

Comment: what kind of objects do you put in the Map and what is the average no of elements you have in the map?

Comment: Isn't the slowness normal for increasing data? I mean if a Map with 100 elements takes 100ms, won't a Map with around 200 elements take around 200ms (roughly speaking). Do you have any numbers which indicate this slowness? I'd rather go with splitting the request and sending it to the server in batches rather than messing around with code for performance reasons unless there is absolutely no way left and your problem doesn't permit splitting requests...

Answer (score 5):

You can use DeflatorOutputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream, however you will end up with a byte[] so your RMI call should return a byte[].

Small serializable obejct won't compress well, however if you have many Serializable objects it can compress very well. So can large amounts of text.

The simplest thing to do is to try it. If there are repeated strings or even portions of strings, this will help compression.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        map.put(""+Math.random(), ""+Math.random());
    byte[] bytes1 = toBytes(map);
    byte[] bytes2 = toCompressedBytes(map);
    System.out.println("HashMap with "+map.size()+" entries, Uncompressed length="+bytes1.length+", compressed length="+bytes2.length);
}

public static byte[] toCompressedBytes(Object o) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(baos));
    oos.writeObject(o);
    oos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static byte[] toBytes(Object o) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(o);
    oos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static Object fromCompressedBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
    return ois.readObject();
}
```

Prints

```
HashMap with 1000 entries, Uncompressed length=42596, compressed length=19479
```

Comment: Why use an intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream at all?

Comment: To get the toByteArray(). Is there another way to get the byte[]?

Comment: See my answer here, it doesn't use ByteArrayOutputStream. It's only really useful if you want stats. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41550311/1247302

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything to the hashmap. Instead, [Write a custom socket factory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/socketfactory/index.html) that compresses the data using a [DeflaterOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may try a [custom serialization mechanism](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) for the elements inside the hashmap.

<strike>What kind of information are you sending? how do the object inside look like?</strike>

Even using the default mechanism, and marking all the unneeded attributes as transient will help.

Additionally you may attempt to sending the data your self serializing it before to a [ZipOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)  but I would let that as a last resource, for the binary content won't compress too much.

**EDIT**

Since your using only strings, you can create an wrapper whose custom serialization is a compressed array ( pretty much as Peter Lawrey answer ) but, using a custom serialization would let you encapsulate the serialization process and have it working some how "transparently" for RMI ( RMI serialization would never know you're using a compressed version )

Here's a demo:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class MapDemo implements Serializable { 

    private Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    // only for demo/comparison purposes, default would use compressoin always
    private boolean useCompression;
    public MapDemo( Map<String,String> map , boolean compressed ) { 
        this.map = map;
        this.useCompression = compressed;
    }

   // This is the custom serialization using compression 
   private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     OutputStream os = useCompression ?  new DeflaterOutputStream( baos ) : baos;

     ObjectOutputStream oos     = new ObjectOutputStream(  os );
     oos.writeObject( this.map  );
     oos.close();

     out.write( baos.toByteArray() );
   }
}

class Main { 
    public static void main( String [] args )  throws IOException { 
        Map<String,String> regular    = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> compressed = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++ ) { 
            String key      = ""+r.nextInt(1000000);
            String value    = ""+r.nextInt(1000000) ;
            // put the same info 
            compressed.put( key , value );
            regular.put( key , value );
        }   
        save( new MapDemo( compressed, true ) , "map.compressed");
        save( new MapDemo( regular, false ) , "map.regular");
    }
    private static void save( Object o, String toFile ) throws IOException  { 
        // This is similar to what RMI serialization would do behind scenes
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(toFile));
        oos.writeObject( o );
        oos.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try invoking "string.intern()" prior to adding them to the map. Hopefully that would reduce the amount of objects in your map and will easy the serialization process.

Comment: I am wondering how interning would improve serialization performance as the strings need to be sent to another jvm anyway

Comment: If there are just strings then @Peter Layer's is a optimal solution

Comment: @Pangea Hopefully, using intern 100 repeated strings would be serialized as only 1.

Comment: Is there any algorithm that can compress upto 90-95 % and also Java provides implementation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I used to serialize objects into byte array and then zip it. Zip is still supported by Java :) so try this method.